# Como criar um Stopwords, utilizando R

Tags: r, classificação

Oi,

preciso fazer uma tarefa e não estou chegando em um raciocínio lógico.

Meu cenário é: tenho um DF com varias colunas, preciso "ler a coluna 3", identificar as palavras e classificar.

Exemplo:

```
DF 

nome      rua    funcao
alberto   assis  programador
elisa     cons   enfermeira
pedro     assis  prog.
```

Quero "ler a coluna 3" e sempre que achar "programador|prog" ou similares, em uma coluna nova "classificacao" colocar "Python", o DF ficaria assim.

DF

```
nome      rua    funcao        classificacao
alberto   assis  programador   Python
elisa     cons   enfermeira    outros
pedro     assis  programador.  Python
```

Algué poderia me dizer se criar um stopWords é a melhor forma de resolver ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, provavelmente não a mais eficiente.

```
dataset = read.table(text = 'nome      rua    funcao
                             alberto   assis  programador
                             elisa     cons   enfermeira
                             pedro     assis  prog.', header = T)


palavras_similares = c("prog.", "Prog", "programador", "Programador", "programador.", "Programador.")

#Posição das palavras encontradas
indice = match(palavras_similares, dataset$funcao, nomatch = 0)

#Vetor auxiliar
classificacao = rep("outros", nrow(dataset))

#Substituindo na posição das palavras encontradas
classificacao[indice] = "Python"

#Atribuindo o vetor ao Dataframe
dataset$classificacao = classificacao

dataset
#     nome   rua      funcao classificacao
#1 alberto assis programador        Python
#2   elisa  cons  enfermeira        Outros
#3   pedro assis       prog.        Python
```

Outro modo utilizando o pacote `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
(dataset <- mutate(dataset, classificacao = ifelse(dataset$funcao %in% palavras_similares, "Python", "Outros")))

#     nome   rua      funcao classificacao
#1 alberto assis programador        Python
#2   elisa  cons  enfermeira        Outros
#3   pedro assis       prog.        Python
```

Answer (score 6):

Para complementar a resposta do @Thiago Fernandes, você pode encontrar padrões similares usando a função `grep()`:

```
dataset[grep('prog', dataset$funcao), 'funcao']
# [1] programador prog.
```

A função `grep()` retorna a posição dos elementos enquanto `grepl()` retorna um `TRUE` ou `FALSE`:

```
dplyr::mutate(dataset, classificacao = ifelse(grepl('prog', dataset$funcao), "Python", "Outros"))
```